# Error with HttpCookie in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, httpcookie

i have been researching for a good while now and cannot figure out why I am getting these 2 errors with my HttpCookie.

My first error is in this line :

```
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
                                        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                                        encryptedTicket
                                      );
```

and error is

> `RestSharp.HttpCookie` does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.

And the 2nd line is below:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

and error is

> The best overloaded method match for 
>   System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.Add(System.Web.HttpCookie) has some
>   invalid arguments

This is my login method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
{

    bool isPersistent = false;

    var client = new RestClient("localhost");

    var request = new RestRequest("api/myapi/", Method.GET);

    request.AddHeader("email-header", user.Email);
    request.AddHeader("password-header", user.Password);

    var response = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;
    var content = response.Content;

    var result = content.Split('"');
    var userId = result[7];
    var apiKey = result[3];

    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,                                                                                // Sets ticket number
        userId,                                                               // Authenticated user Id
        DateTime.Now,                                                                     // Issue date
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes),                // Expiration date
        isPersistent,                                                                     // Persists across browser sessions          
        apiKey,                                                                      // Authenticated Api Key
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);                                             // Path for the cookie


    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    // Fails here
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

    cookie.HttpOnly = true;

    //Fails here
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(user.Email, isPersistent));
    return View();

}
```

What I am using:

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
//using System.Web;
using System.Web.HttpResponse;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
```

Solution to my problem:

Had to replace

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

With

```
System.Web.HttpCookie cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: And what is the error!

Comment: haha sorry,  the first one is 'RestSharp.HttpCookie' does not contain a constructor that contains 2 arguments.

Comment: Side note: while adding error text to the post try to reformat your sample to avoid horizontal scrolls.

Comment: 2nd one is, The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpCookieCollection.Add(System.Web.HttpCookie)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Roger that, will remember next post.

Comment: Shawn, please edit your post and add the error messages inline (prefix with ">" so they formatted nicely).

Comment: I dropped to new lines, I hope that works well.

Answer (score 2):

You are using different class than you expect - it looks like you have code that should be using [System.Web.HttpCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but instead it picked up `RestSharp.HttpCookie`.

Fix - specify full class name:

```
  var cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie(
      FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
```

Comment: I tried this same line.  It gives me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Web.HttpCookie' to 'RestSharp.HttpCookie'.  I have to use "using RestSharp" for my API call tho.  This is what is confusing me lol.

Comment: Added my uses to original post

Comment: Ok I found the answer, thank you for the help.  Got me on the right track @Alexei Levenkov